# Pivotal Cloud Foundry - Connect React FE to Spring Boot BE

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, cloud-foundry, pcf

We have two applications deployed to PCF:

- A Spring Boot REST Backend on a route e.g. backend.route1.net deployed with java_buildpack_offline
- We also have our React Frontend on the same instance on a route e.g. frontend.route1.net pushed with a Staticfile with a single line content of: `pushstate: enabled`

Both works separately, which we can confirm by accessing the endpoints on both directly, for which they clearly return the expected values, hence they are both working well.

However, as soon as we try to access a page on the Frontend that needs to talk to the Backend using Axios we get a ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

The generic things I find on Google or in PCF Documentation don't seem to be helping. Any tips where should I continue looking or what the actual issue could be?

If you need further info please ask.

Thanks!

/András

Comment: `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` would imply that you have some sort of certificate error. Where do you see that error? Maybe include a screenshot. Also, expand on how certificates are configured in your lab. It is odd though that your browser would navigate to the site, but yet throw a TLS error when doing so from Javascript. Definitely check the Javascript Console/Network tab of DevTools for more possible details.

Comment: I'm not sure it'll necessarily help, but you might want to try using routes that are on the same hostname, so instead of `frontend.example.com` and `backend.example.com` use `app.example.com/backend` and `app.example.com/frontend` or something like that. You can rule out potential CORS issues that way. An alternative is to use something like Spring Cloud Gateway, to sit in front of your application & then use an internal route to talk to your backend app. Your JS traffic would then proxy through SCG. You only end up with one domain, so you rule out CORS issues.